# Trying to reverse the contents of the file and reverse the file's name into a new file?

Tags: c++, binary, reverse, fstream, ifstream

So here's my code, but I don't know how to make the new file's name the original file's name reversed. 
    #include

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
string text;
ifstream orig;

reverse(name[0],name[name.size()]);
orig.open(argv[1],    ios::binary);

char *c = new char[1];

if(orig) {
  orig.seekg(0, orig.end);
  int length = orig.tellg();
  orig.seekg(0, orig.beg);
}

while(orig.read(c,1)) text += c;
std::reverse(text.begin(), text.end());

ofstream reverse("copy.dat");
reverse << text;

orig.close();
reverse.close();

return 0;
}
```

Comment: The code example does not even compile.

Comment: `char *c = new char[1];` Huh, why do you think this is needed rather simply having `char c`??

Answer (score 0):

Allocating a single `char` array instead of just using an automatic array is wasteful, and forgetting to `delete` it causes a memory leak, but a vanishingly small inefficiency compared to the O(N2) complexity of the main loop.

You should allocate get the filesize, allocate an array of `char` of said size and  read it in one call to `read`.